# Voltage Drop across Diode

Tags: voltage, diodes, step-down

I have a 6V input on my board. I need to put a load switch for USB 3.0 which needs 5V. I need to stepdown 6V to 5V using a series diode. 6V is going to other circuits also.

Can someone suggest the diode I can use & what parameters should I consider while selecting a diode.

Comment: What is your minimum and maximum load current?

Comment: Load current is for USB 3.0 i.e 900 mA.

Comment: You also need to know the **minimum** current your load might take.

Answer (score 1):

A diode won't do the job. The voltage drop will decrease as the current decreases leaving anything plugged in exposed to more than 5 V.

I suspect you need a LDO (low drop-out) voltage regulator with current limiting. The current limiting will protect your supply and anything else running on it.

Comment: I agree. But in case I need to use a diode only, which one would it be?

Comment: I would use a couple of 1N4000 series diodes in series but that would drop 1.2 to 1.4 V at that current and might leave you on the low side of 5 V. They're rated at 1 A so you may wish for a higher safety margin too. Go through the common diode spec sheets - particularly the V-I charts and pay attention to the effect of temperature.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use Schottky diodes instead. That has forward voltage drop from 0.7 to 1V but be cautious it has a high leakage current.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a zener diode in parallel with your power source.
You probably need a current limiting resistor so that you don't burn up your diode.